# changed logic when using dotCover and optimizied code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit, dotcover

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with one of our unit tests when running it with dotCover.

Essentially the unit test calls a method and passing `double.NaN` as parameter to. The method compares the provided parameter whether it is outside of an allowed range. If it is outside of the range, an exception is thrown.

This code illustrates the code:

```
[TestCase(double.NaN)]
public void Test(double testValue)
{
    if (testValue < 0.0 || testValue > 30.0)
    {
        Assert.Fail($"This shouldn't fail less={testValue < 0.0}, greater={testValue > 30.0}, all={ (testValue < 0.0 || testValue > 30.0)}");
    }

    Assert.Pass("all good!");
}
```

Since `double.NaN` doesn't equal anything, the `Assert.Fail` should never get called.
This is true in general, with one exception.
When the code is compile with `Optimize Code` turned on (e.g. Release configuration) and dotCover is used for analyzing code coverage.
In this case, the if statement gets entered. Here is what the output looks like:

> This shouldn't fail less=False, greater=False, all=False

I found a few ways to alter the code to make it work without actually changing the logic itself.

1. assign comparison to local variable

   ```
   bool isNotValid = testValue < 0.0 || testValue > 30.0;
   if(isNotValid)
   ```
2. separate if statements

   ```
   if(testValue < 0.0)
   {
       Assert.Fail(...);
   }
   else if(testValue > 30.0)
   {
       Assert.Fail(...);
   }
   ```
3. single `|` operator

   ```
   if (testValue < 0.0 | testValue > 30.0)
   {
       Assert.Fail(...);
   }
   ```
4. check explicitly for `double.NaN`

   ```
   if (!double.IsNaN(testValue) && (testValue < 0.0 || testValue > 30.0))
   {
       Assert.Fail(...);
   }
   ```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?
I would like to avoid adding code into our code base just for the sake of making dotCover happy.

I'm using:

- VS 2017
- dotCover 2017.3.2
- NUnit 3.10.1.0

Answer (score 0):

We have found a bug in dotCover, which leads to this behavior. The fix will be available in ReSharper 2018.2 version. We expect to release it within several months. Sorry for the inconvenience.